# c# windows service process.start

Tags: c#, windows-services

I did create a windows service. Can I add in the `OnStart(string[]args]` method the `Process.Start` - used to open another executable. Will it work? I want to create an windows service application that opens an executable file (foor example cmd where i can add my own commands to open a notepad file . Thx

Comment: It seems like you know enough to try it, so why don't you just try it?

Comment: i've tried it and i have error

Comment: In that case, post the code you used to try it and give us the full details of the error (that way we're not wasting our time doing the same exact thing you did).  Also - did you specify that this service would interact with the desktop?

Comment: now i don't have any error but the UI does not pop up. Using Process.Start I want to open a programm.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to allow the service to interact with the desktop (under service properties in Services mgr), but is sometimes considered a bad [practice](http://asprosys.blogspot.com/2009/03/allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop.html). Note, this is made difficult in Windows 2008 and above because of [Session 0 isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It works, but the rights the process run, as well as the resources it can see are the same as the wiundow service ( ie Local System Account ) if you don't change the defaults. This could make the difference or not, depends on what the executable do. If the executable has to show some UI you will experience troubles since by default the servcie does not see the user desktop. The same happen if you need to see a mapped network drive. In general it works if the executable is some batch that does not requires th econnected user profile right/resources.

Comment: i am connecting the windows service with a UI. Now i don't have any tipe of errors, but the UI is not popping up when I start my windows service application. why? any ideas how to do it?

Comment: @elisa read the kd7 reply, it explain this. I feel something wrong in launching an ui from a service... since the service can exist without any user logged in. Maybe you better change the architecture.

Comment: thf for advice Felice. Even if it's wrong do you have anyideas why the process.start that calls an executable that has an GUI is not working? Is there another way i could do it? i really need this. i can't think to other architecture. thx

Comment: because as kd7 wrote the service should have the "interact with desktop" flag set.